# All-inclusive CSS selector for input elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Looking for a way to apply a background-color to all input elements, including dropdown lists, textareas, and even checkboxes.

Is there an all-inclusive selector for this sort of thing, or would I need to list them all individually in the selector?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of them are covered in `input`, so all you need to add is the two others:

```
input, textarea, select { }
```

But no, there's nothing more all-inclusive than that.

Comment: in jQuery you can do `:input` but this question wasn't about jQuery so this comment is pointless! :D

Comment: Thanks kindly, to the both of you.  I suspected as much, but figured I'd check anyway.

Comment: Hey while we're at it, I couldn't figure out a way to change the background-color of the checkboxes, even before I asked this question.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing for altering the style of all form elements that are required (here using Foundation 5 with Abide validation): `form *:required` Works in Chrome so far.